# Throwing an exception in afterAll disrupts the display in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I'm writing a `scalatest` suite the is using the `BeforeAndAfterAll` mixin.
When running the tests in intellij, if an exception if thrown in the `afterAll` function, the result panel becomes class hierarchy becomes incorrect.

here is a sample code to recreate

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite}


trait BaseBrokenTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {
    test("test 1") {
      println("test")
    }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    println("afterAll")
    ???
  }
}

trait BasePassingTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {
    test("test 1") {
      println("test")
    }
}

class Test1 extends BaseBrokenTest
class Test2 extends BaseBrokenTest
class Test3 extends BaseBrokenTest
class Test4 extends BaseBrokenTest
class Test5 extends BasePassingTest
class Test6 extends BasePassingTest
```

When I run all tests, it will look like this:

[image]

When there are a lot of test suites, it becomes very difficult to track the failed and succeed tests in that way

is there a way to fix it?

the versions I use:
scala: 2.11.11
scalatest: 3.0.4
intellij: 2017.2.3 community edition

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL.

Comment: already opened: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12914